# preg_match condition problem

Tags: php, preg-match

I wan't to check if a string ($nick_2) got " or ñ

Is this correct? i can't make it work

```
if ( (strlen($nick_2) >= 3) && (strlen($nick_2) <= 25) && (!preg_match("/\"/", $nick_2)) && (!preg_match("/ñ/", strtolower($nick_2))) ) {
```

Comment: It works well for me. Maybe problem is in other place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For finding single characters, regexes are massive overkill. Just use

```
if ((strpos('"', $nick_2) !== FALSE) || (strpos('ñ', $nick_2) !== FALSE)) {
   ... chars were found
}
```

Comment: and if the true should be chars were not found?

Comment: strpos returns boolean false if the character isn't found. it can also return a 0 if the char is at the start of the string, which would get treated as a false, which is why you have to use the strict inequality check (!==).

Comment: So i should use === because my true statement needs that chars weren't found, right?

i've got 
        if ( (strpos('"', $nick_2) === FALSE) && (strpos('ñ', strtolower($nick_2)) === FALSE) ) {
... chars not found
}

Comment: Make sure the character encodings are correct throughout your software stack and that it's not `&ntilde;` in the raw string, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly your string is in UTF-8, in which case, you must use the `u` modifier in `preg_match` and should submit your expression to that function also in UTF-8.

If that's the case, you will also want to do some of these things:

- Replace `strtolower` and `strlen` with `mb_` alternatives.
- [Normalize](http://php.net/normalizer) the input.
- Check if the graphemes where those characters are don't have more code points.